# Popup windows on page load with specific period

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup

on my page I need to set up a pop up window with special offer but I dont want to harass my customer everytime they go on homepage so I want to use cookies for chcecking and show popup up for specific period. For example once a week woud be great. I am a newbie in javascript, I just downloaded and use Reveal pop up plugin but I dodnt know how to set up it.

here is my code:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css">

    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jquery.reveal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
```

This is pop up window

```
<body>
....
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
         <h1>Modal Title</h1>
         <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
         <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

And now I can run it just by clicking on link that looks like thaht

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
```

But I want to load it on pageload with cookies. 
You can view sample on page page by clicking on orange label Click Me For A Modal below the header.
http://mmiuris.sk

Thanks for any ideas.

**Edit:**
The script is working finr but I cant make reveal plugin box to appear (it doesnt even make cookie file)
The code looks like this, see any error ?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.reveal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var c_value = document.cookie;
            var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
            if (c_start == -1) {
                c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
            }
            if (c_start == -1) {
                c_value = null;
            }
            else {
                c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
                var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
                if (c_end == -1) {
                    c_end = c_value.length;
                }
                c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
            }
            return c_value;
        }

        function showModal() {
            // Check if cookie existes
            var expireDate = getCookie("showpopup");
            var today = new Date().toUTCString();
            alert(today);
            if (expireDate != null && expireDate > today) {
                //Do nothing!
            }
            else {
               //ShowPopup here!
                        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myModal').reveal();
        });
                //Create cookie
                setCookie("showpopup", "anything", 1);
            }
        }    
   </script>
   </head>

 <body onLoad="showModal()">    
        <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
         <h1>Modal Title</h1>
         <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
         <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

...
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code on you homepage. Modify it to show the popup instead of the alert in the show modal. This example sets the cookie to expire everyday. Change it to 7 days or whatever value you want...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var c_value = document.cookie;
            var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
            if (c_start == -1) {
                c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
            }
            if (c_start == -1) {
                c_value = null;
            }
            else {
                c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
                var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
                if (c_end == -1) {
                    c_end = c_value.length;
                }
                c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
            }
            return c_value;
        }

        function showModal() {
            // Check if cookie existes
            var expireDate = getCookie("showpopup");
            var today = new Date().toUTCString();
            alert(today);
            if (expireDate != null && expireDate > today) {
                //Do nothing!
            }
            else {
                //ShowPopup here!
                alert('This is the popup!');
                //Create cookie
                setCookie("showpopup", "anything", 1);
            }
        }        
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks but how do I change  alert('This is the popup!'); to some script that will work like that <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a> (this open the popup) . On plugin site there is written "Basically, put the "data-reveal-id" attribute on an object and make it's value the ID of your modal." But i dont get it.

Comment: Try this : $('#myModal').reveal();

Comment: it doesnt work :/, i googled and tried another variant but doesnt work too...see any mistakes in that code ? (upaded my first post) thanks

Comment: It'S missing the setCookie and getCookie methods... Did you read any error messages?

Comment: I am using  setCookie and getCookie methods I just posted part where I made changes

Comment: I updated my first post, do you see any mistake why Reveal popup doesnt show ? It works fine with alert message, but I want to pop that Reveal plguin. Thanks

Comment: thanks, i have it problem was in more jquery libraries conflict